# Difference between unwind segue and delegation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, delegates, uistoryboardsegue

I wonder if anybody can explain the difference between using a unwind segue and using delegation in the example I have below:

I have a `FriendsTableViewController` populated by an `array` of friends and another `AddFriendTableViewController` with a function to add a `friend` to the `FriendsTableViewController`.

This is how I send the data from my `AddFriendViewController` with a `unwind segue`:

```
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check whether the Done button was tapped.
    // If it wasn’t, instead of saving the friend, the method returns without doing anything else.
    if (sender != self.doneButton) return;

    // See whether there’s text in the text field.
    if (self.nameTextField.text.length > 0) {
        // If there’s text, create a new friend and give it's properties the input from the text fields.
        self.friend = [[Friend alloc] initWithName:self.nameTextField.text
                                          dateOfBirth:self.birthdayDatePicker.date
                                        numberOfGifts:0];
    }
}
```

This is how I add the data from the `AddFriendTableViewController` to the `array` in `FriendsTableViewController` with the `unwind segue action`:

```
#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)unwindSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // Retrieve the source view controller, the controller that is unwinding from.
    AddFriendTableViewController *soruce = [segue sourceViewController];

    // Retrieve the soruce view controller’s friend object.
    Friend *friend = soruce.friend;

    // See whether the item exists.
    // If it’s nil, either the Cancel button closed the screen or the text field had no text, so you don’t want to save the item.
    if (friend != nil) {
        // If it does exist, add the item to the friends array.
        [self.friends addObject:friend];

        // Reload the data in the table.
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Now this works as I want so I hope I'm not breaking any stackoverflow rules or offending anyone, but I just wanted to know what is the difference between the way my example code is used and if the same scenario was made but with custom delegate methods for the `AddFriendViewController`. If some can explain it would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an unwind segue is very similar to having a delegate, with the following advantages:

- You don't need to implement any dismiss logic
- You don't need to pass references up and down the navigation stack
- You don't need to declare a delegate protocol
- It's trivial to unwind back a number of stages in your app

The disadvantages are

- Dependent on using storyboards (which may hamper reusability)
- If there are a lot of them, it can lead to the same messiness as you can get in `prepareForSegue` with a lot of branching off identifier names
- If you decide to present the view controller via some other method (not a segue) then you can't unwind back from it

The code you have looks good. I'd stick with it.

Comment: thank you so much for explaining this and thanks of a thorough and detailed answer! I'll mark this as accepted as I now got both pros and cons when using unwind segue :)

Comment: +1 for the last one. "If you decide to present the view controller via some other method (not a segue) then you can't unwind back from it". I was almost sold but that is a deal breaker in my mind. Protocol/Delegate pattern keeps the view controller self contained and portable and therefore, I believe, the better option.

Comment: Yes I also agree on that point, but in the project that I'm implementing the with "unwind segue way" in is quite small and I felt that this approach is sufficient for the project!

Comment: Is there any memory management issue with unwinding segue? Do unwinding segue use weak reference like delegates in protocol ???
Please give me answer if anybody knows.

Comment: @NiteshBorad no, there are no memory management issues. If you have something specific in mind, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks jrturton for reply.
Do unwinding segue use weak reference to parent viewcontroller like delegate in protocol uses?
Does it produce "strong reference cycle"?

Comment: @NiteshBorad segues don't cause reference cycles. They don't exist for long enough.