# Whats the difference between moving between Storyboard scenes - Segues and Unwind

Tags: ios

I'm a fresher. I used segue to go (Flow of Execution) such like that

```
 UIViewController A => UIViewController B => UIViewController C.
```

And used unwind segue to move from **C to A**. But I am confused about how they different of each other.
And Why I use unwind segue  although I have delegation.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: There're many ways to bring data backward eg. Unwind, Delegate, Block, NotificationCenter, just use what is most convenient, if u using segue, then unwind is very convenient, delegate/protocol serve a lot more purpose than just pass data backward

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between unwind segue and delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633574/difference-between-unwind-segue-and-delegation)

Comment: Thanks @KiritModi and Tj3n

Comment: @Roshanboy4u Okkk..

Answer (score 1):

Regular Segue allows us to send data from one view controller to another, but it’s not easy to bring data back if the user has changed or added details in that view controller. That’s where an Unwind Segue comes in.

[Read more here](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-an-unwind-segue-in-ios-8/)

Answer (score 1):

Segues are for presenting a new view controller.

Unwind Segue is a special kind of segue (A go back mechanism) which moves back to the connected destination.

A->B->C->A

If you are using segue for above mentioned flow, there will be two different instance of A in the memory.

If you use unwind segue for the C->A transition

1. It act as a go back mechanism and it removes the C and B instance from the memory once the segue is over
2. There will be only 1 instance of A